# Creating Select Then Zoom Tool using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, zoom

I have been trying to create a tool to make a simple select then zoom to selected but I've been running into some issues. I've been using the code from this original posting (https://community.esri.com/thread/217697-select-layer-by-attribute-python-script-tool). It seems like his solution was never solved.

Here is the code that I have:

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "PARCELS", df)[0]
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/ArcMap/COGO_Template"

wrk = arcpy.env.workspace
arcpy.AddMessage("Workspace added")
FClass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
Feature = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

FClassLayer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(FClass, "FclassLayer")

where_clause = """{} = '{}'""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(FClass, Field),
                                      Feature)  # I have added extra pair of single quotes for selecting strings
arcpy.AddMessage(where_clause)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(FClassLayer, "NEW_SELECTION", where_clause)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(FClass, "C:/ArcMap/COGO.gdb/SelectionSites")
df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.AddMessage("All done!")
```

My parameters are as follows:

InputFeatureClass = Data Type: Feature Class, Required, Input, No Multivalue, Default: Database Connections\Connection to gis.sde\PARCELS

InputField = Data Type: Field, Required, Input, No Multivalue, Obtained from Input Feature Class

InputValue = DataType: String, Required, No Multivalue

The tool runs fine and shows no errors but unfortunately no parcel is selected and it doesn't zoom. Something to note as well is it takes about 2 minutes to run.

When I manually select by attribute in the attribute table (select, select by attribute, put in the parcel number, click ok), then run the tool, it zooms to the layer

Comment: Your script will get simplified by using a layer's `definitionQuery` property, as in the duplicate's answer.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include an answer and give thanks; this breaks the Q/A model used by GIS SE. The [Someone Answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) page covers this

Comment: How do I answer my own question though so I don't disrupt the model?

Answer (score 1):

Flaws in your code are:

1. You get a handle on a layer called "PARCELS" but then do nothing with it.
2. You create a variable `wrk` and do nothing with it.
3. Your Copy Features is being run on the FEATURECLASS not the FEATURELAYER which has the selection.

Comment: I've removed the first two and changed the CopyFeature to the FeatureLayer. This is a bit of an add-on question, but is there a way I can select an attribute without having to create a feature class? I've read a bit about using "in_memory", but am unsure.

Comment: @TaylorKravits "add-on questions" should be asked as new questions.

Comment: In_memory is a sort of temporary geodatabase so yes you could copy features to that location.